# "I'm sorry, I haven't written (or "haven't been writing") to you for a while" - which is better?

Tags: present-perfect, progressive-aspect

My question is simple. Which one sounds more natural to you?

1) I'm sorry, I **haven't written** to you for a while.
2) I'm sorry, I **haven't been writing** to you for a while.

I think **2** is better. Do you agree?

PS: To me the combination of "for a while" and "haven't written" sounds odd. "For a while" chimes with a lasting/repetitive action better. But "haven't written" is not a lasting/repetitive action. That is why I thought "haven't been writing " was better.

Comment: It's just a matter of opinion / stylistic preference / precise nuance. If you'd previously been *in the habit of writing **regularly***, for example, you might wish to accentuate that by using format #2. From that perspective, #1 could be seen as more "neutral" (it's certainly more *common* if we consider all contexts where either form might feasibly be used). On that basis I'm voting to close as Primarily Opinion-based.

Comment: To me the combination of "for a while" and "haven't written" sounds odd. "For a while" chimes with a lasting/repetitive action better. But "haven't written" is not a lasting/repetitive action. That is why I thought "haven't been writing " was better.

Comment: Are you a native speaker? In actual fact I'm quite certain your example #1 is the more common usage, regardless of whether the utterance includes something like *for a while*. The main reason for using #2 (less common, but also in no way "odd") would be emphasize the "disconnect" between a previously *habitual* activity and the fact that *you're not doing it **now*** (or at least, *weren't*, until you started the current missive).

Comment: I, by no means, am arguing or trying to establish a superiority of my opinion. I am just analyzing all the elements of the sentences. And I am not native.

Answer (score 3):

To me, the first choice sounds more natural. It emphasizes the nature of writing to someone as an intermittent action. The second, as FumbleFingers noted, seems to emphasize that the speaker has been in the habit of writing to the person in question.

Either one implies that the speaker should have been expected to write to the person referenced. The second, though, implies that the expectation is based on past experience, i.e. previously the speaker was *in the habit of* writing to them. With the first, all we can conclude is that there is a social expectation (thus both the apology and the implied definition of "a while."

Comment: To me 1 sounds as a one-off action.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I haven't written to you *in* a while.

I'm sorry I haven't been writing to you *for* a while.

Comment: What  about that "to you". Isn't that redundant? _I'm sorry I haven't written in a while._

Comment: It's not redundant, but neither is it necessary.